# How to accept an unknown number of inputs on one line?

Tags: python

I know how to accept multiple inputs on one line, but I can only do that if the number of inputs is pre-defined. In this code segment:

```
rows, tile1, tile2, column, tile3 = map(int, input().split(" "))
```

I want the number of inputs in between row and column to depend on the number inputted in row, and I want the number of inputs after column to depend on the number inputted in column, but I can't quite figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, you can use this syntax:

```
a, b, c, d, *e = map(int, input().split())
```

`a`, `b`, `c` and `d` will be the first four values, and `e` will be a list of all the remaining values.

In your case, you'll need to do something like this:

```
rows, *rest = map(int, input().split())
```

Since you don't know in which position the `column` value will be, I'm afraid you will not be able to use this feature for what you want to achieve.

If you can make the user input both `rows` and `columns` before the rest, you could do it like this:

```
rows, columns, *tiles = map(int, input().split())
```

And then you could refer to specific tiles as `tiles[0]`, `tiles[1]` and so on.

Comment: That makes so much sense. It never occurred to me to use the star operator. Thanks!

Comment: @str1kebeam - [Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)